# Preventing BI Emit material from lighting through objects

Tags: light

I have a material with emit (Blender Internal renderer) on top of a cube with deep hole on it. What I expect is the light should not be able to get into the hole. However it is as if the top of the cube does not exist at all and light the hole completely. (Reducing indirect lighting bounce to 1 makes the ceiling of that hole dark, understandably)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any way to make a material blocks emitted light?

Changing the emit material's transparency mode to Raytrace helps a bit, but not completely.

[image]

Z transparency ones for comparison

[image]

Comment: Did you enable Raytracing in the Render tab > Shading rollout? Or try using Spot lamp instead which by default is the only one casting shadows in BI.

Comment: Yes I have Raytracing. Turning it off does not affect emit light but removes the shadow in the hole caused by the default point lamp.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate, probably not identical, but it seems that indirect lighting is the factor mostly affecting that... I just reduced it from 1.0 to 0.2 here:

[image]

turning it off removes the colored shade completely (but also on the top face of the bottom cube):

[image]

Since indirect lighting here works only with "approximate" gather (if you use "raytrace" gather it works better and is very similar to turning off indirect like above), I guess that "approximate" word means: faster, but it does not fit well in all situations...

eg:

[image]